# Regex to determine if a file is a rar file

Tags: c#, regex

i've been messing around trying figure this out myself but its taking a while..

Basically after a regex to pass the following tests:

```
IsARarFile("test.rar"); // true
IsARarFile("test.r00"); // true
IsARarFile("test.txt"); // false
IsARarFile("test.avi"); // false
IsARarFile("test.mp4"); // false
IsARarFile("test.001"); // true
IsARarFile("test.ba00"); // false
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: What are you doing this for? Depending on the use case, it might be better to check that first four bytes of the file's data is "Rar!" instead of assuming based on the file extension. (Especially since other things might use "test.001")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\.(?:rar|r\d\d|\d\d\d)$
```

I think.

Edit: Credit to Peter for another correction.

Comment: Why do you need to capture? use (?:...)

Comment: Since your edit it now seems to work

Perfect, basically I just want to know which files in a directory are rar files. Seems pretty simple now that I look at it :)

Comment: Just to understand then, the \. is saying that check for a '.' then either: rar 
or 
r digit digit 
or digit digit digit?

Comment: Jeffrey Friedl would probably formulate himself differently, but yes, you're correct :)

Comment: @BenW yep. Although the regex will match a file named '.000' (ie: no filename)

Comment: This answer is wrong! Currently it will match "wr00ng.gif" and various other incorrect values, since the alternation is including the `\.` and `$` in first and last alternatives.

It should only have one set of parens, surrounding the alternatives, like this: `\.(?:rar|r\d\d|\d\d\d)$` so that the `\.` and `$` are distinct from the extension choices.

Answer (score 5):

```
([^\.]+)\.(r(ar|\d\d)|\d{3})$
```

Comment: +1 I like this one, however I feel the readability is better in Reinderiens answer, at least for people not familiar with regular expressions.

Comment: The first part is incorrect - both because the `.` doesn't need escaping inside a char class, and because filenames can have multiple `.` characters in them. (It might not be sensible to have a file called e.g. `.....rar`, but it's still valid.)